# SwiftUI - Grab angle of circle on drag

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to grab when the user drags across a circle specific angles of where they are dragging. What is happening is the angle will decrease initially - and around a quarter of the way through the angle will increase again, repeating angle values.

How can I prevent this so the angle will be a full 360, without repeating? I suspect it may be I'm calculating the radians or angle incorrectly.

```
struct TabWheelButton: View {
    var circleWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2.5
    var text: String
    var angle: Double
    var index: Int
    @Binding var current: Int

    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -angle))
            .padding()
            .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
            .background(current == index ? Color.green : Color.blue)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 80, style: .continuous))
            .offset(x: circleWidth / 2)
            .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: angle))
    }
}

struct CircularDisplayForTab: View {
    @Binding var current: Int

    func onChangeOfTabWheel(value: DragGesture.Value) {
        let vector = CGVector(dx: value.location.x, dy: value.location.y)
        let radians = atan2(vector.dy, vector.dx)
        var angle = 180 - (radians * 180 / .pi)
        
        print(angle)
        if angle > 0 && value.translation.width != 0 {
            if angle > 91 && angle < 96 {
                current = 1
            } else if angle > 96 && angle < 99 {
                current = 2
            } else if angle > 99 && angle < 106 {
                current = 3
            } else if angle > 246 && angle < 250 {
                current = 4
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        let circleWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2.5
        let circleHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        
        Circle()
            .trim(from: 0.24, to: 1.0)
            .stroke(Color.blue.opacity(1.0), lineWidth: 60)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 20))
            .frame(width: circleWidth, height: circleHeight)
            .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0).onChanged(onChangeOfTabWheel(value:)))
        TabWheelButton(text: "H", angle: 145, index: 1, current: $current)
        TabWheelButton(text: "B", angle: 215, index: 2, current: $current)
        TabWheelButton(text: "P", angle: 285, index: 3, current: $current)
        TabWheelButton(text: "S", angle: 355, index: 4, current: $current)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showAdditionalTabFeatures = false
    @State private var current: Int = 1

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Press me") // show circle
                .onTapGesture {
                    showAdditionalTabFeatures = true
                }
        }
```

Comment: Can you show your desired result with a screenshot?

Comment: Your example code seems a bit incomplete. The body of ```ContentView``` does not contain much and the tappable text "Press me" does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The switching you're seeing may be because `atan` seems to flip by 180 degrees (or pi radians) when the adjacent side goes from a positive to a negative value.

However, I would have thought the angle dragged should be computed as *endAngle* - *startAngle*, where start and end are measured from the center of the circle. This means, the drag gesture needs to be supplied with the dimensions of the circle.

The following drag gesture reports the drag angle (in degrees) that is computed in this way, where 12 o' clock represents 0 degrees:

```swift
    private func location2Degrees(location: CGPoint, midX: CGFloat, midY: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let radians = location.y < midY
            ? atan2(location.x - midX, midY - location.y)
            : .pi - atan2(location.x - midX, location.y - midY)
        let degrees = radians * 180 / .pi
        return degrees < 0 ? degrees + 360 : degrees
    }

    private func measureAngle(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) -> some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged { value in
                let midX = width / 2
                let midY = height / 2
                let startAngle = location2Degrees(location: value.startLocation, midX: midX, midY: midY)
                let endAngle = location2Degrees(location: value.location, midX: midX, midY: midY)
                let dAngle = endAngle - startAngle
                print(dAngle)
            }
    }
```

If the circle dimensions are given then it is straightforward to supply these to the gesture:

```swift
        Circle()
            // other modifiers here
            .frame(width: circleWidth, height: circleHeight)
            .gesture(measureAngle(width: circleWidth, height: circleHeight))
```

Otherwise, if the circle dimensions are determined by the parent container then you could perform drag on an overlay layer and use a `GeometryReader` to get the size, something like this:

```swift
        Circle()
            // other modifiers here
            .overlay {
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    Rectangle()
                        .opacity(0.001)
                        .gesture(measureAngle(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height))
                }
            }
```

Better still, put the `Circle` inside the `GeometryReader` (in place of the `Rectangle` above), then it doesn't need the opacity trick.